# Next() em CSV Reader com Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, machine-learning

Olá, eu estou fazendo um curso de Machine Learning/Classificação e bem ele utiliza um arquivo CSV no qual deve-se ignorar a primeira linha do arquivo. Então fiz o seguinte código:

```
import csv

def carregar_acessos():

    X = []
    Y = []

    arquivo = open('acesso_pagina.csv', 'rb')
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)
    leitor.next()

    for home,como_funciona,contato,comprou in leitor:

        dado = [int(home),int(como_funciona),int(contato)]
        X.append(dado)
        Y.append([int(comprou)])
```

Porém quando o executo informa que o "leitor" não possuí atributo NEXT. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Retorno do Terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifica_acesso.py", line 3, in <module>
    X,Y = carregar_acessos()
  File "/Users/josecarlosferreira/Desktop/machine-learning/dados.py", line 11, in carregar_acessos
    leitor.next()
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Segundo o que é mostrado na aula o código está correto e deveria funcionar. Mas tentei procurar sobre a mudança no Next, e testei outros códigos que encontrei e bem continuava dando erro.

Obs: A primeira linha do Arquivo CSV é um Texto e todas as outras são números inteiros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa usar a função `next()` em vez de um método com esse nome.

Assim:

```
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)
    next(leitor)
```

Na biblioteca padrão de Python os iteradores implementados em C suportam diretamente a função `next()`. Classes implementadas em Python podem implementar um método chamado `__next__` para suportar a função `next()`.

Seja seja como for implementado o iterador, o jeito recomendado para acessar o próximo item é chamar `next(meu_iterador)`.

Comment: Perdão, mas não acho que tenha entendido muito bem o que quis dizer.
Se o meu código não está implementando o next() quer dizer que preciso implementar o __next__ ? Mas onde seria implementado isto?

Desculpa, estou descobrindo o mundo da programação e tem muitas coisas que ainda me deixam um pouco confuso.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def carregar_acessos():
    X = []
    Y = []

    arquivo = open('acesso.csv', 'rb')
    leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)

    next(leitor)

    for home,como_funciona,contato, comprou in leitor:

        dado = [int(home),int(como_funciona)
            ,int(contato)]
        X.append(dado)
        Y.append(int(comprou))

    return X, Y
```

Comment: Bem, eu tentei desta forma e ele continuou não aceitando. Dizendo que havia algo de errado com o Iterador.

Comment: http://carlosmaniero.blogspot.com.br/ cara da uma olhada neste blog, pode ser que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso a versão 3.61 aqui, coloquei o código desta forma e funcionou 100% , o que deve ser observado é atenção para detalhes, pois vc colocou a leitura de um arquivo csv(txt) como "rb" read binary ? apenas coloquei "r" e pronto tudo certo!
import csv

def carregar_acessos():
    X = []
    Y = []

```
arquivo = open('csvpy.txt', 'r')
leitor = csv.reader(arquivo)

next(leitor)

for home,como_funciona,contato, comprou in leitor:

    dado = [int(home),int(como_funciona)
        ,int(contato)]
    X.append(dado)
    Y.append(int(comprou))
    print(X)
    print(Y)

return X, Y
```

carregar_acessos()